# Merge objects in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, merge, javascript-objects

first post, new to programming, excited to learn!

The Problem:
How do I merge all the objects (strings) into a single array?

EX:

```
var myStrings = ["How", "", "do", "", "I", "", "merge", "", "these?"]

Desired result = ["How do I merge these?"]
```

My research:
I've tried `.join('')` but that gives:

```
Not desired result = How,,do,,I,,merge,,these?
```

Thank you for helping a newbie!

Comment: `Merge objects in array` FYI, they are known as `strings` not `objects`. _and no answer below explain that_

Comment: `myStrings.reduce(function(a, x){return (a + " " + x).trim(); }, "")`

Answer (score 2):

You could filter with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for truthy values (like not empty strings)

> ```
> value    Boolean
> 'abc' -> true
> ''    -> false
> ```

and the join with `' '`. Then take it as an element of a new array.

```js
var myStrings = ["How", "", "do", "", "I", "", "merge", "", "these?"],
    result = [myStrings.filter(function (a) { return a; }).join(' ')];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Probably worth explaining that `""` coerces to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by,

```
var myStrings = ["How", "", "do", "", "I", "", "merge", "", "these?"];
var result = [myStrings.join(" ").replace(/\s\s/g, " ")];
console.log(result); // ["How do I merge these?"]
```

Try to `join` the array by a single space as I given above. And replaces the double spaces with a single one. This has to be done since you are having empty strings in your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStrings = ["How", "", "do", "", "I", "", "merge", "", "these?"]

myStrings.join('').split(',,').join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.forEach()` to iterate array, if item is not empty string concatenate item to new string, else concatenate space character `" "` to new string.

```
var res = [""];
myStrings.forEach(function(str) {res[0] += str !== "" ? str : " ";});
```